# Can't access laravel app running in docker container on mac

Tags: php, laravel, docker, dockerfile

i am trying to access my simple laravel app running inside of a docker container on my MacOS (docker desktop v4.25.0) i want to access this in my browser. tried different ways but couldn't.

```
docker run -d --name hello-laravel -p 8080:9000 hello-laravel:latest
```

i have exposed port 9000 in my docker file.
how do i get the ip of my docker host ? i ran

```
docker inspect hello-laravel --format '{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}'
```

and got the following ip

```
172.17.0.2
```

but i believe this i my container ip

Comment: What about `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: doesn't work with either localhost:8080 or 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: did you add `CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=9000` at the bottom of the dockerfile, after which you should be able to visit `localhost:8080` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I already commented but I am answering the question so it can be marked as answered.*

---

You are never telling the docker container to serve the Laravel application.
In order to do this, you should add the below snippet to the end of your Dockerfile. The snippet runs the following command in the container; `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=9000`.

Telling your container to 'serve' the application on a certain host and port.

```yaml
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=9000
```

Once you've done this you can access the application using; `localhost:8080`

---

**Why use `--port=9000`?**

The port you exposed in the Dockerfile should be used here, in your case 9000.

**Why use `localhost:8080`?**

You've port-forwarded the 8080 port on your host to 9000 in your container.